# mysql data search with varchar type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
From checkfinale 
where AssociateID = 51 AND 
      `CompletedDate` >= '16/04/2012' AND 
     `CompletedDate` <= '22/06/2012'
```

ComplitedDate is varchar type. because I am using view. when I am trying to execute it those dates not effecting in condition. Is there any error?

Comment: "ComplitedDate is varchar type. because I am using view" --- uhm? Because "what"? The only correct way of working with dates in mysql - is to use appropriate types to store them

Comment: You have found the first (OF MANY) issues you will encounter if you store dates as varchars. As zerkms says, use the appropriate type (a datetime). Most of the answers below give you workarounds, but please, PLEASE rethink your storage types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the CompletedDate to date, then exeucute.

So your query goes like this

```
SELECT * From checkfinale 
where AssociateID = 51 AND 
    STR_TO_DATE(CompletedDate,'%d/%m/%Y') >= '16/04/2012' 
   AND STR_TO_DATE(CompletedDate,'%d/%m/%Y') <= '22/06/2012'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, if CompletedData is of type varchar, then your date comparison isn't going to work. You are just comparing strings, not dates or timestamps

Answer (score 1):

**Please store your date using the `Date` type**

Or use `STR_TO_DATE` to format your `varchar` to a date.

```
SELECT * 
From checkfinale 
where AssociateID = 51 AND 
      STR_TO_DATE(`CompletedDate`,'%d/%m/%Y') >= '16/04/2012' AND 
      STR_TO_DATE(`CompletedDate`,'%d/%m/%Y') <= '22/06/2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)** Function.

> This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string
>   str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value
>   if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or
>   TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the
>   date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal,
>   STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM checkfinale 
 WHERE AssociateID = 51 AND 
      ( STR_TO_DATE(CompletedDate,'%d/%m/%Y') >= date('2012-04-06') AND 
        STR_TO_DATE(CompletedDate,'%d/%m/%Y') <= date('2012-06-22') )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings and need to compare them as dates, use the CAST() function.

```
SELECT * 
From checkfinale 
where AssociateID = 51 AND 
 CAST(`CompletedDate` AS DATE) >= '16/04/2012' AND 
 CAST(`CompletedDate` AS DATE) <= '22/06/2012'
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast